# proving existence of a particular linear operator on the space of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functional-calculus

I am having trouble solving this task:

Let $X:=C_b([0,\infty))$ be the space of bounded functions $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the norm $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}|f(x)|$.
Show that there exists a continuous linear functional $L:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$Lf=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$$
for all $f\in X$ for which the limit on the right hand side exists.

I really have no idea how to do this at all. I am currently studying for an exam and found this task in an old exam of 2013.
Basically i have to find a continuous function $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)dx=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$$
This means that $g\in L^1([0,\infty))\cap C^0([0,\infty))$. But i have no idea where to start.
Maybe one could first find a functional on the subspace $Y\subseteq X$ given by $Y=\{f\in X: \|f\|\leq 1\}$ and then extend it with Hahn Banach, since then for any $f\in X$ we could use 
$$Lf=\|f\|L\left(\frac{f}{\|f\|}\right)=\|f\|\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\|f\|}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$$
any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ be the subset of $Y$ such that $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)$ exists Just write $L(x)=lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)$ on $Y$, it is linear and its bounded. Suppose that $\|f\|\leq 1$, this is equivalent to $Sup_{x\in [0,+\infty)}|f(x)|\leq 1$, you deduce that $|lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)|\leq 1$. So $L$ is a linear bounded function and is continuous. You can apply Hahn Banach to extend this to $X$.

Comment: It is not continuous. For example one could take $f=1$ and $g=1/(1+x^2)$. Then their distance is 0 but $|Lf-Lg|=1$

Comment: If tthe distance between two elements is zero they are equal.

Comment: But w.r.t. the norm their distance is 0...

Comment: $|1-{1\over{1+x^2}}|=|{{x^2}\over{1+x^2}}|$ and $sup_{x\in [0,+\infty)}|{{x^2}\over{1+x^2}}|=1$ is not zero.

Comment: Right my bad. But it would be $x^2-1$ and I'm sure that's not the answer they were looking for. Linear functionals are supposed to be defined on the whole space. And this wouldn't be true for your case. It wouldn't be defined for $sin(x)$.

Comment: why it wouldnt be true here ?

Comment: We are looking for a linear functional on $X$, and not on the functions for which the limit exists